# Is this a standing or moving wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

The electric field of a uniform plane wave traveling in a source free region of free space is given by:
$ \vec E= (0.5j \vec x + \vec y)(e^{j \beta z} - e^{-j \beta z})$.  Is this a traveling wave or a standing wave.

Now I am stuck at the point if this is standing or travelling wave? According to me this should be neither as there is no variation with time. This is a time invariant Electric Field. So, this should be neither standing nor travelling wave. Am I correct? Or do the question assumes that this is a phaser quantity only & I need to introduce the time variant part myself. As I am new to em waves, this small doubts may arise. Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $e^{jx} - e^{-jx} = 2j \sin(x)$

So what you have written is not an electromagnetic wave at all. It is an electric field with a fixed direction and an amplitude that varies sinusoidally along the z-axis.

Of course if you *multiply* this by $e^{j\omega t}$, then you do have a wave. Given the wording I suspect you are meant to assume this (though I think that is poor practice). If so, then 
$$ \vec{E} = (0.5j\vec{x} + \vec{y})(e^{j(\omega t + \beta z)} - e^{j(\omega t - \beta z)})$$
This consists of two individual components that are travelling plane waves of equal amplitude but in opposite directions. The sum of these will be a standing wave (the product of a sinusoidal function of time and a sinusoidal function of $z$).